# Tomcat certificate issue - continued

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, keytool, java-6

I have imported: root, intermediate, server certificates into the Java Keystore for Tomcat for Windows.

These are VeriSign (commercial) certificates..

We cannot use keyAlias for the connector - ssl page never comes up.  Port 80 or standard web traffic is fine, but ssl is not.  What is curious to me about this, is that one of our server guys did say that it is acting like we had a self-signed cert installed..

Our current \tomcat\conf\server.xml has:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="C:\NewCert\keystore.ks" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

What is interesting out of this, we see the following error:
"There is a problem with this website's security certificate"
Going to the web page (https://servername.domain.local:8443) - and we requested the certificate as servername.domain.local ..  Consequently, we see: "Untrusted Certificate"
When viewing the certificate from the website versus the one from our CA has a different ThumbPrint.

I have read that we are supposed to be able to import the root/intermediate/server certificates as one file (*.p7b) - and when doing so, keytool responds back to say this is not an X.509 certificate.  But, I do believe that if I can get the .p7b file imported, it would be what we need..

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe" -import -trustcacerts -file "C:\NewCert\ap01.p7b" -keystore "C:\NewCert\keystore.ks" -alias "tomcat" -storepass "changeit"
```

And the resulting message is:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Thanks.

Comment: The p7b was the magic way to do this.  Once imported with Java's keytool, the certificates and chain were properly aligned and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might help with the pkcs7 import.

[Import PKCS7 (Chained Certificate) using KeyTool command to JKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814569/import-pkcs7-chained-certificate-using-keytool-command-to-jks)

Understand that a root CA cert is by definition a self-signed cert.  You probably have a number of them being trusted by the JVM at the very least.  I'd look at the keystore, make sure everything is in it properly.  Look at the cert you get from the server, if it's not right, find where it's coming from.  If it's right, make sure the root CA is trusted by the browser and not explicitly untrusted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [web-based tool](https://github.com/chiralsoftware/CertWeb) that does all this for you, from generating the key, creating the CSR to importing the chain, without having to use keytool at all.